# How to return all values from Laravel pluck() method of a nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel

this is the code from the controller to pluck the values from the sdoh categories that the household chooses

```
foreach ($households as $household) {
    $chosenSdohCategories = $household->sdoh->pluck('pivot.sdoh_category_id')->toArray();
}
```

**HouseholdHead model:**

```
public function sdoh()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SDOH::class, 's_d_o_h_category_households', 'household_head_id', 'sdoh_category_id');
}
```

**SDOH model:**

```
public function sdoh_category()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SDOHCategory::class, 'sdoh_id', 'id');
}

public function household_heads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Household::class, 's_d_o_h_category_households', 'sdoh_category_id', 'household_head_id');
}
```

but when I dump the results, it is only returning half of the array :

```
array:8 [▼ // resources\views/details-household-modal.blade.php
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 5
  3 => 7
  4 => 9
  5 => 12
  6 => 13
  7 => 15
]
```

**Database Query Logging:** and I don't understand it as well, I added it if it is helpful

[image]

this is my sdoh_category_households table:

[image]

based from the table, the array must contain 15 values, but the code is returning 8 values only.

I want to return all the values from the sdoh_category_id that belongs to household_id number 25, but is only returning 8 values.

Comment: This is not a problem with the `pluck` method. Show us how you define the relationship.

Comment: the results don't match what is in your table as well e.g. `2` in the result set is not in your shared dataset so it does look like a problem with how you are defining your relationship

Comment: Why don't you just put ->sdoh()->pluck('id)?

Comment: Shouldn't you expect an array in foreach loop, so assigning variable could be more like `$chosenSdohCategoriesp[] = /**/`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy HouseholdHead model has sdoh function  : 

public function sdoh()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SDOH::class, 's_d_o_h_category_households', 'household_head_id', 'sdoh_category_id');
    }



SDOH model:
public function sdoh_category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SDOHCategory::class, 'sdoh_id', 'id');
    }

    public function household_heads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Household::class, 's_d_o_h_category_households', 'sdoh_category_id', 'household_head_id');
    }

Comment: @StewieSWS i tired it, and the results is the same

Comment: @Tpojka can you please elaborate ? I did not get it, sorry

Comment: In each iteration `$chosenSdohCategories` is being overwritten. Try with setting `$chosenSdohCategories = [];` before loop, and `$chosenSdohCategories[] =  $household->sdoh->pluck('pivot.sdoh_category_id')->toArray();`. Then `dd($chosenSdohCategories)` after loop to check what is there.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
foreach ($households as $household) {

    $chosenSdohCategories = $household->sdoh()->where('household_head_id', $household->id)
                                              ->get()
                                              ->pluck('sdoh_category_id')
                                              ->all(); // Use ->all() to get an array

    dump($chosenSdohCategories);
}
```

Comment: They're already calling `toArray()` to get an array, and the point of a relationship is so you don't have to have manual `where()` clauses all over the place.